Eshell cannot execute filesystem objects that are NTFS reparse points on Windows
None of the executables inside C:/Users/Me/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps can be run from the command line under eshell.
The error I receive when trying to run any of these executables looks like:

Opening input file: Invalid argument,
C:/Users/Me/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/notepad.exe

What I've been able to glean so far is that these executables, all of which are 0k in size, are in fact NTFS reparse points which contain metadata that is supposed to be read by the appropriate filter driver.
In a cmd.exe or pwsh.exe console under windows, I can run this notepad.exe executable from the command line without any problem.  So I think the problem has to do with eshell not being able to handle filesystem objects that are NTFS reparse points.
Could not find any additional information on this by searching the web.
An obvious workaround is to call cmd.exe /C notepad.exe from inside eshell, but I would like to better understand why eshell cannot call any of these executables directly.
Any thoughts?

Jim Porter (bug-gnu-emacs) reported this as a known bug

unarchive 71655
forcemerge 71655 74150
thanks

that is already fixed in emacs 30.
